# How to load a new image on the Image Control each time the Button Control is pressed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

As the topic, how do I keep load a new image (from a set of images already onto the app) each time the Button Contro is pressed? Either in a random or sequential manner? The image would ofcourse be loaded onto the Image Control.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well you mean that if you have eg image1,image2,image3,image4 etc you want everytime you press the same button the image element will change into the next image.

if i am right on this you have to asign a public variable let's name it counter so

```
public int counter = 1;
```

and in onclick action you should enter

```
counter++;
image.Source = new Uri("/Images/Image"+counter+".jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the content property button and add imagebrush as it content.

```
<Button>
<Button.content>
<imagebrush x:name=btnContent imageSrc="" />
</Button.content>
</Button>
```

on button click in the cs file

just change the image source of the image brush

```
btnContent.imageSource=new BitmapImage("");
```